# Rewind past a block of text in VT100 terminal commands

Tags: c, terminal, vt100

I basically want to manipulate the output of some program connected to a terminal so that the bottom section of text is always some arbitrary block of text (let's call it the footer), while the normal output of the program is displayed above that. If this footer was confined to a single terminal line, this would be very easy to do by simply clearing the current line, moving the cursor to the beginning of the line before each `write` call, and then rewriting the footer. However, if my desired footer spans multiple terminal lines, either by including newline characters or by lines wrapping around the edge of the screen, things are complicated. I thought I might be able to work around that with the "save cursor" and "restore cursor" VT100 control codes, which would be emitted as such for every write:

1. restore cursor
2. desired `write` call
3. save cursor
4. output footer

However these don't work when the output text reaches the bottom of the terminal because the saved cursor will always be at the bottom row.

Is there any way achieve this arbitrary terminal footer? Something with just VT100 codes would be ideal, but if the only way is to use curses then I suppose that's possible, too.

Comment: is the therminal subject to being resized?

Comment: That's why they wrote the [`curses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) library a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a scrolling region.  Something like this (keeping in mind that while you could hard-code escape sequences, this is more readable):

```
#!/bin/sh
rows=$(tput lines)
foot=$((rows - 4))
tput csr 1 $((foot - 1))
count=0
while true
do
        date
        count=$((count + 1))
        tput sc
        tput cup $foot 1
        printf "Total cycles %d", $count
        tput rc
        sleep 1
done
```

Comment: The scrolling region `<ESC>[{start};{end}r` looks like it will do the trick. I just have to make a maximum number of rows for the footer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the VT100 doesn't allow text windows, or fixed scrolling windows (perhaps a better term).

So, that leaves it to you to manage.

Curses would be easiest because you could, in your code, just open two separate windows, one for the "text", one for the footer, and then let curses update the screen as it sees fit.

With just raw VT100, you would have to track when to scroll. When you do scroll, you could delete the top line, then insert a blank line just before your footer, and then write on the new blank line.

Curses would handle all of that for you, of course.